# How can I setup a remote desktop connection?

Tags: remote-desktop

My desktop is more powerful than my laptop, and thus I would like to be able to remotely use my desktop from another computer. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on the laptop and mint 17 on the desktop. Better yet if I can do remote desktop connection to a Windows computer, especially without admin privileges if possible, at my school.

Comment: hi @rajlego , be well-aware that a great remote desktop experience is worse than a bad desktop one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried remmina? I run it off my Ubuntu box at work to connect to Windows Servers and I haven't had any issues with it.

Link -> http://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/remmina

Comment: I checked it out, but I don't really know how to use it. Could you explain its use for remote desktop connection?

Comment: Here's a pretty good guide on it, post-install: http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/how-to-install-remmina-remote-desktop-client-on-ubuntu-11-10/